# Will default theme pages affect my seo?

Tags: seo

I'm using a pre-built wp theme and when I check my site like: site:siteurl.com i see the default pages also indexed by Google. For example "sidebar-left", "sidebar-right" etc. The theme's default pages in general.

My first question is: will this negatively affect my seo?
Should I remove them or just leave it there?

Comment: I've never seen WordPress create pages for things like that.  Sidebars are usually parts of pages and don't get their own URLs.

Comment: Well, in my experience, default theme pages may not affect your seo. Even if google crawled some your default pages with default contents, it will not affect your site seo.